# Translating Ruby enum symbols with Rails I18n?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums, internationalization, rails-i18n

Because I'm quite new to Ruby and Rails, I'm not entirely sure about how best to word this question, but here's my situation. I've been tasked with translating a Japanese web app built in Rails to English, and I've mainly been doing that by creating a long list of words/phrases in the config/locales/ja.yml and en.yml files and referencing them in the views by using t('...').

However, I now have a situation where a drop-down selection form is pulling values from a model's enum.

The relevant line in the model:

```
enum gender: %i(男性 女性)
```

The relevant line in the view:

```
<%= f.select :gender, User.genders.keys.to_a, {}, { class: "form-control" } %>
```

I've been trying various things to little avail, including trying to use solutions involving the enum_help gem.

If possible, I'd like to avoid changing the line in the model, since this is part of a much larger code base that I don't know much about, but if it's necessary, I'll have to. How can I most easily translate the drop-down box to appropriately say "男性" and "女性" for Japanese, but "Male" and "Female" for English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `config/locales/en` for example, you will have:

```
views:
  genders:
    male: "Man"
    female: "Lady"
```

Then in your view:

```
<%= f.select :gender, User.genders.keys.collect { |g| [t("views.genders.#{g.downcase}"), g] }, {}, { class: "form-control" } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its quite easy.

1. Install the gem translate_enum

> gem install translate_enum

2. Include TranslateEnum in the model

> ```
> class Gender < ActiveRecord::Base
>
> include TranslateEnum
>
> enum gender: { male: 0, female: 1}
> ```

3. In the view file:

`f.select :gender, options_for_select(Gender.translated_statuses.map {|translation, k, _v| [translation, k] })`

4. Finally in the `config/locales/en.yml` file:

   ```
   activerecord:
    attributes:
      gender:
        gender_list:
          male: "Male"
              female: "Female"
   ```

Hope this works fine!